# How to receive notification from a GridView when it refreshes?

Tags: android, gridview

A `GridView` has `BaseAdapter` derived class responsible for populating its children.  It works fine.

I want to do something when the `GridView` is refreshed. In other words, I wish there was a method "addOnRefreshListner()".

It needs to accommodate API Level as low as 8 (Froyo).

Answer (score 0):

What if you override BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in your custom adapter?

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // A change has happened and caused the GridView to refresh
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I should have mentioned that I have tried both notifyDataSetChanged() and notifyDataSetInvalidated(), but they are never called.

Comment: You need to call it when you change your data with methods like `add()` or set up a DataSetObservable.

Comment: Sometimes the GridView refreshes even when there is not data change. For example, it may happen when the size changes.  Such change invokes getView() of the adapter for each child.  I want to get the notification after all the children are updated. View.OnLayoutChangeListener() appears to be the right one, but unfortunately, it works for API 11 or higher.

Comment: Have you tried extending GridView and overriding `invalidate()`?

Comment: No, I have not.  I am trying to get away without extending GridView.  I never thought this would be difficult until I started looking into it. Originally I thought there would probably be multiple methods to choose from to accomplish this. Class View has all kinds of setOnXXXListener, but none of them seem to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged()`  is the solution to the absence of your addOnRefreshListener().

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing a `View.OnLayoutChangeListener()` for API 11 or higher.

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
myView.addOnLayoutChangedListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

      // Do what you need to do with the height/width since they are now set
    }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry but I should have mentioned that I need to accommodate API level 8 and above.  I will edit the question to add this condition.